# Alguém conhece um bom tutorial sobre ACL no Symfony 2?

Tags: php, symfony, acl

Estou iniciando um projeto novo e resolvi usar o Symfony, gostaria de saber se alguém conhece um bom tutorial sobre acl e/ou roles para eu poder implementar.

A hierarquia que vou precisar utilizar é mais ou menos essa:

> Master > Empresa > Departamentos > Células > Funcionários

Quando eu logar no sistema, terei que identificar de qual célula sou, qual meu departamento e qual a empresa.

A partir desta análise eu poderei dizer quais clientes o usuário logado poderá acessar, e quais as permissões de CRUD que ele tem, e quais campos ele pode ver e/ou alterar.

NA verdade estou em dúvida se uso ACL ou uso papéis simplesmente, por isso precisaria entender bem os dois para tomar a decisão.

Answer (score 1):

Um bom começo é a documentação de "Security" do próprio Symfony: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html

Você vai levar algum tempo lendo, mas garanto que isso vai te poupar de dúvidas posteriores.

Ele vai explicar a diferença entre authentication e authorization, como o firewall do symfony funciona (Authentication) e finalmente como usar ACL com roles.

Acredito que a parte de ACL vai te atender bem. Elas são bem flexíveis, permitindo criar regras do tipo:

Usuário / Roles

- João - Admin_Mega_Foda Funcionario
- Maria - Contabilidade Funcionario
- Joana - Chefe_Contabilidade Contabilidade Funcionario

Conteúdo / Roles

- Cadastro da Clientes (Ler e Gravar): Contabilidade Admin_Mega_Foda
- Cadastro da Clientes (Apagar): Chefe_Contabilidade Admin_Mega_Foda
- Documentação interna da empresa: Funcionario

Só vai complicar, se houver alguma regra muito específica sobre um cliente que só pode ser visto por um usuário, e gravado por um outro.

Na barra de desenvolvedor do Symfony, você pode conferir qual o usuário logado e quais roles esse usuário têm.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o FOSUserBundle para fazer o gerenciamento de usuários da sua aplicação.

Nas configurações de segurança da aplicação é possível definir as roles, por exemplo, ROLE_MASTER, ROLE_EMPRESA, ROLE_DEPARTMENTO, ROLE_CELULA e ROLE_FUNCIONARIO, e aí usar as próprias funcionalidades do FOSUserBundle para criar, alterar e excluir usuários.

A documentação deles é muito boa e deve te ajudar em todo o processo de adaptação da aplicação às funcionalidades do bundle :)

Answer (score 0):

Documentação oficial é suficiente:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html

Em português:

http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=en&tl=pt&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fsymfony.com%2Fdoc%2Fcurrent%2Fcookbook%2Fsecurity%2Facl.html

Answer (score 0):

Existe um tutorial traduzido para português sobre segurança do Symfony2 : http://www.duocriativa.com.br/janela/symfony-em-portugues/book/security